# Add texture to character model

Tags: texturing

I've recently downloaded this character model from a website that looks like this:[image: Character model with textures on]

But when I opened the model in Blender, it came out like this:[image: Model with no textures]. I also have the texture files with me[image: Texture files].

So how do I add the textures to the model?(BTW, I don't know anything about Blender).

Answer (score 1):

Select your character, open the *Shader Editor* window, click on the *New* button, add a *Texture > Image Texture* node, plug it into the *Base Color* socket of the *Principled BSDF*, and in this *Image Texture* node, load your PNG:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a uv map to unwrap the texture on the model, but I think its better that you look for a youtube tutorial. Questions here are more especific, so that you find information that is not already in the web. It would be harder to explain that here, I thik.